# Joining tertile to quarter SQL (4-month periods to 3-month periods)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose we measured the appearance of turtles three times a year, in tertiles (three 4-months periods). Then we switched to quarters (four 3-months periods). I would like to compare the values of the current year with the previous year.

**Edit thanks to Steve comments.** Originally I used the wrong word for 4-month period calling it *trimester*. The right word for the 4-month period is [**tertile** or **quadrimester**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23262/is-there-a-proper-term-to-describe-1-3-of-a-year-4-months).

```
+------+--------+------------+------------+----------+
| year | period |     d1     |     d2     | value_cy |
+------+--------+------------+------------+----------+
| 2018 | T1     | 2018-01-01 | 2018-04-01 |       10 |
| 2018 | T2     | 2018-05-01 | 2018-08-01 |       20 |
| 2018 | T3     | 2018-09-01 | 2018-12-01 |       30 |
| 2019 | Q1     | 2019-01-01 | 2019-03-01 |       18 |
| 2019 | Q2     | 2019-04-01 | 2019-06-01 |       16 |
| 2019 | Q3     | 2019-07-01 | 2019-09-01 |       14 |
| 2019 | Q4     | 2019-10-01 | 2019-12-01 |       12 |
+------+--------+------------+------------+----------+
```

and this is desired results:

```
+------+--------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| year | period |     d1     |     d2     | value_cy | value_py |
+------+--------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 2018 | T1     | 2018-01-01 | 2018-04-01 |       10 |          |
| 2018 | T2     | 2018-05-01 | 2018-08-01 |       20 |          |
| 2018 | T3     | 2018-09-01 | 2018-12-01 |       30 |          |
| 2019 | Q1     | 2019-01-01 | 2019-03-01 |       18 |      7.5 |
| 2019 | Q2     | 2019-04-01 | 2019-06-01 |       16 |     12.5 |
| 2019 | Q3     | 2019-07-01 | 2019-09-01 |       14 |     17.5 |
| 2019 | Q4     | 2019-10-01 | 2019-12-01 |       12 |     22.5 |
+------+--------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
where
    Q1=3/4 * T1
    Q2=1/4 * T1 + 1/2 * T2
```

My effort:

The idea which comes to my mind is an intermediate table which translates the period from trimesters to months and then to quarters.

```
+--------+-------+
| period | month |
+--------+-------+
| Q1     |     1 |
| Q1     |     2 |
| Q1     |     3 |
| Q2     |     4 |
| Q2     |     5 |
| Q2     |     6 |
| Q3     |     7 |
| Q3     |     8 |
| Q3     |     9 |
| Q4     |    10 |
| Q4     |    11 |
| Q4     |    12 |
| T1     |     1 |
| T1     |     2 |
| T1     |     3 |
| T1     |     4 |
| T2     |     5 |
| T2     |     6 |
| T2     |     7 |
| T2     |     8 |
| T3     |     9 |
| T3     |    10 |
| T3     |    11 |
| T3     |    12 |
+--------+-------+
```

I wonder however if it might be done by two self-joins of the source table, first join on the closest possible date equal or earlier, second on date equal or equal or later. Having those two dates and their differences to source date we could calculate the results.

Comment: You say you want to compare current year with previous year. At what level of granularity do you want to do the comparison? Compare the entire year? By month? By quarter?

Comment: Just a nitpick, but you do realise a *trimester* means a period of three months (i.e. is synonymous with a *quarter*)?

Comment: @Steve yes, you are right. Thanks. I will edit my question.

Comment: @dfundako at quarters

Comment: +1 for the word "tertile" as meaning generically "a part of any thing divided into thirds" (c.f. quartile). Also, for the unexpected comedy of "measuring turtles ... in tertiles"!

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you don't want to continue recording data in trimesters in the future (i.e., this can be solved with a one-time operation), and that you are working with SQL Server, you could preprocess your trimester data into quarterly data in the same table first to make your comparison easier. Something like the following would give you your Q1 and Q2 values:

```
-- Q1 rows
INSERT INTO data_table (year, period, d1, d2, value_cy)
SELECT year, period, d1, d2, t1_component.value_cy FROM
(
    SELECT
        year,
        'Q1' AS period,
        CONCAT(year, '-01-01') AS d1,
        CONCAT(year, '-04-01') AS d2,
    FROM
        data_table
) main
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT 0.75 * value_cy AS value_cy
    FROM data_table
    WHERE year = main.year
    AND period = 'T1'
) t1_component;

-- Q2 rows
INSERT INTO data_table (year, period, d1, d2, value_cy)
SELECT year, period, d1, d2, t1_component.value_cy + t2_component.value_cy FROM
(
    SELECT
        year,
        'Q2' AS period,
        CONCAT(year, '-05-01') AS d1,
        CONCAT(year, '-08-01') AS d2,
    FROM
        data_table
) main
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT 0.25 * value_cy AS value_cy
    FROM data_table
    WHERE year = main.year
    AND period = 'T1'
) t1_component
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT 0.5 * value_cy AS value_cy
    FROM data_table
    WHERE year = main.year
    AND period = 'T2'
) t2_component;
```

You can get the Q3 and Q4 values by adjusting the above queries as needed. Once you have all the values in quarterly format, you could do a self-JOIN to get the previous year's results alongside the current year's, although this would be slow due to having to JOIN on a calculated value (this may suit your needs though):

```
SELECT
    cy.year,
    cy.period,
    cy.d1,
    cy.d2,
    cy.value_cy,
    py.value_cy AS value_py
FROM data_table cy
INNER JOIN data_table py
    ON py.year-1 = cy.year
WHERE cy.period IN ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4')
```

Alternatively, you could take a look at the [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) operator, which basically transforms a row value in a column header:

```
 SELECT period, [2019], [2018]
 FROM
     (SELECT period, year, value_cy FROM data_table WHERE period IN ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4')) AS src
 PIVOT
     (value_cy FOR year IN ([2019], [2018])
 AS pivotTable
```